# Multi Tenancy using IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, dns, multi-tenant, iis-8

I want a functionality like slack, user will have there domain name followed by company name and for that I have implemented multi tenant using .NET Core and its working perfectly in my local:

[image]

I have published the code on IIS and also setup the wildcard(`*.mydomainname`) in DNS but its not working there.

Could anyone please guide what else I need to setup.

However, I have followed this link: [Wildcard Host Header Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/wildcard-host-header-support)
 but it seems only support in above version of IIS 10 and we have IIS version 8

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/wildcard-host-name-support-in-old-iis-releases-8e4448040b5a

Comment: As Lex Li said, you can support wildcard host header through the ARR and URL Rewrite module in ii8.